# NSUserDefaults not saving in table cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

When I replace the `@"hello"` with titlestring the table, the cell shows up blank, If i leave the hello, everything works, including the "detailsstring". I don't know why it's doing that since detailsstring is set up exactly the same as titlestring.
here is the code:
in the .m file I have

```
@synthesize  detailsstring;
@synthesize  titlestring;
```

and it's all defined the same in the .h in the .m I have this as well:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{        
    titlestring =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"titletext"];
    detailsstring = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"details"];

    tabledata = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"hello", nil];
    tablesubtitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:detailsstring, nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Now, I'm saving those Userdefaults in another controller. Here is the save button action in a different view controller:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *titletext = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [titletext setObject:titleTextfield.text forKey:@"titletext"];

    NSUserDefaults *details = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [details setObject:detailstextfield.text forKey:@"details"];

    NSUserDefaults *categoryUser = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [categoryUser setInteger:selectedCategory forKey:@"category"];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also, how are you using tablesubtitles? Is there anything holding a reference to that?

Comment: `[super viewDidLoad]` should be the first thing you should call on the `viewDidLoad` method. That won't solve the problem you are having but that is definitely something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: You don't have to create a separate `NSUserDefaults` object for each string/integer you save- each `NSUserDefaults` object that you create is just a new pointer pointing to the same `NSUserDefaults` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, one instance of `NSUserDefaults` is sufficient for all three modifications. To 'push' the changes to the file system immediately, you can call `[userDefaults synchronize];`. Otherwise there is no guarantee that your changes are saved instantly. Apple suggests only to call this method if you cannot wait for the changes to be saved.

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:titleTextfield.text forKey:@"titletext"];
    [userDefaults setObject:detailstextfield.text forKey:@"details"];
    [userDefaults setInteger:selectedCategory forKey:@"category"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

In your `viewDidLoad:` method, try to output the saved values to test your application's integrity:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"details"]);
```

Comment: Additionally, if you're just testing your app and exit it very early, chances are high it is not saved in the short time span the app is running. I had to deal with that myself.

Comment: `synchronize` only has to do with writing the results to disk (flash storage for iOS). You don't need to call `synchronize` in order to read a value you just set to user defaults.

Comment: Well, if nothing is saved to the disk in the first place, how would you be able to read user defaults?

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is an in-memory data structure. You can write to it and immediately read from the same data from it just like an `NSDictionary`. Occasionally it is also saved to disk. If you crash between the time you write to it and the time it saves to disk, you could lose information. If that information is very critical and you can't afford to lose it even if you crash, then you should call `synchronize`. But in general there's no need to call it.

Comment: Yes, but the OP tries to read the values in `viewDidLoad:` so I assume he does it right after starting the application and successively saves the values. If he terminates the application before iOS had a chance to save the changes and restarts (builds) it, he won't be able to retrieve the data.

Comment: Agreed. Very insightful. I have this issue all the time myself but hadn't considered it applying in this case.